# Office documents on intranet all requiring second login and can't pass auth? Disable webdav?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, webdav, microsoft-office

I am not sure what is going on, but recently all the Office documents on our intranet get prompted a second time for login and according to the error logs it looks like it's trying to use webdav to open (an editable?) version of the document to save directly on the server? We have no sharepoint server setup or anything, but this shouldn't be happening. All I want is for the document to be saved or opened from a local copy in temp like normal.

Here is the log:

```
Line 57499: 2011-04-12 15:57:10 (ip) OPTIONS (address) - 443 (username) (user ip) Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601 - 401 1 1326 1525 238 0
Line 57500: 2011-04-12 15:57:10 (ip) OPTIONS (address) - 443 (username) (user ip) Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601 - 401 1 1326 1525 238 0
Line 57501: 2011-04-12 15:57:10 (ip) OPTIONS (address) - 443 (username) (user ip) Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601 - 401 1 1326 1525 238 0
```

The log basically contains a bunch of these.

How can I disable this behavior so that office documents that are downloaded aren't attempted to be used through webdav??

Edit: I should clarify behavior, it asks if you want to save or open it, upon choosing open open, it asks to re-authenicate, you put in the user information and the login box comes up 3 times acting like you entered the wrong password. For some users, after passing the login box the third time, it still opens up, for others their browser just locks up.

It also doesn't even look like webdav is installed on our server, I see no config options in IIS for it as outlined on this page: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/350/installing-and-configuring-webdav-on-iis-7/#001

Comment: Is this happening on all servers or just one in particular?

Comment: @David Wise we only have 1 web server. The page that contains the links, the documents to be downloaded, the auth, it all resides on one server using iis 7 and server 2k8 r2.

Comment: When you browse to the the site containing the documents, does it say "Internet", "Intranet" or "Trusted Site" in the bottom right of the IE status bar?

Comment: @David Wise it says `Internet | Protected Mode on`, we using basic auth and NTFS permissions for our intranet. I may be mis-using the term intranet, but it's just a password protected site on the web via basic auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open IE and browse to the server you are having troubles with then go to tools - Internet Options - Security - Local Intranet and click on "Sites" then click on "Advanced" and add the url to the "websites" box. Since this is an intranet server anyway, it really should be listed in the Intranet zone in IE.

You should no longer be prompted to login in either IE or in Office when opening the documents from that server.

My bet is that something happened on the clients (either a patch or a change to corporate policies) that pushed the URL back to your Internet zone, which requires a login.

Comment: Hi Dave, appreciate your response, but this didn't fix it, the error still occurs. Also, the problem with your solution is that I don't want user to be able to edit the document on the server just by opening a link to it. I want it to act like a normal download, it shouldn't be trying to open it for editing directly on the server, but I don't know how to disable this.

Comment: Well, one thing to try then is to simply block the verbs "OPTIONS" and "PROPFIND" from your site.  This can be done directly in IIS or in the web.config for the site.

Comment: what would the code be for that? Having some difficulty finding examples. Would this interfere with network shares that users access through mapped drives though? I just searched my logs and see instances of OPTIONS firing when people open office files from their mapped share. Also from what I'm reading, woudln't that just outright prevent those files on the site from being accessed? Seems like it would just return a 404.6 instead of a 401.1 then.

Comment: Nevermind, it worked!